# Retrieving multiple Google Analytics rows for one product were a product scoped customDimension value differ in Google Big Query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have the following Google Analytics data:

**GA field description:**

Product is hits.product.v2ProductName

ProductSKU is hits.product.productSKU

Product Long SKU (CD) is a product scoped dimension and the index is 13.

**Sample data:**

Product,    Product SKU,        Product Long SKU (CD)

Liadalen turbukse dame, 307500, 10223990074006

Liadalen turbukse dame, 307500, 10223990001009

Liadalen turbukse dame, 307500, 10223990074010

Using the query below (inspired by YUHUI) I can only achieve to receive one row being the MAX row that has the largest Product Long SKU (CD). I cannot wrap my head around how to produce the exact data as my sample above in BQ as in three rows but the Product Long SKU (CD) is the variation?

```
SELECT
  p.productSKU,
  p.v2ProductName,
  MAX(IF(pcd.index = 13,
      pcd.value,
      NULL)) AS productCustomDimension13
FROM
  `59546646.ga_sessions_*`
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(customDimensions) AS cd
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS h
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customDimensions) AS hcd
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.product) AS p
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(p.customDimensions) AS pcd
  WHERE
  _table_suffix BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE('2020-04-01')) AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE('2020-05-01'))
  AND h.eCommerceAction.action_type = "6"
  AND p.v2ProductName = "Liadalen turbukse dame"
GROUP BY
  p.productSKU,
  p.v2ProductName
ORDER BY 
  p.v2ProductName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact output you want, but if you only want to list the products, you can use that query:

```
SELECT
  p.productSKU,
  p.v2ProductName,
  (SELECT pcd.value FROM UNNEST(p.customDimensions) pcd where pcd.index = 13) AS productCustomDimension13
FROM `59546646.ga_sessions_*`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS h
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.product) AS p
WHERE
    _table_suffix BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE('2020-04-01')) AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE('2020-05-01'))
    AND h.eCommerceAction.action_type = "6"
    AND p.v2ProductName = "Liadalen turbukse dame"
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY p.v2ProductName
```

If you don't have any aggregations, you can delete group by and add distinct after select statement.
Also, depending on your need, you should add/remove unnest statements.

Comment: Hi Sabri, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so very much.